# Z3:unknown result in Z3 C API

Tags: z3

In current Z3 context,assert " try(X,i,j) = ((X[i][j] == i*j)) " is already existed.the type of X is (Array Int (Array Int Int)).try(X,i,j) is a function and return type is bool.here is the Z3 context:

```
 (kernel
      (forall ((Y (Array Int (Array Int Int))) (i Int) (j Int))
        (let ((a!1 (= (+ (select (select Y i) j) (* (- 1) j i)) 0)))
          (= (try Y i j) a!1))))
```

I want prove Z3 ast:

```
 forall i[0..99],j[0..199]. try(X,i,j) 
    =>
       (forall i[0..49],j[0..199]. try(X,i,j) 
    &&  forall i[50..99],j[0..199]. try(X,i,j))
```

in other words, I check is not of this assert is sat.
Z3 check result is unknow.
but when i prove Z3 ast:

```
forall i[0..99],j[0..199]. (X[i][j] == i*j)
=>
  (forall i[0..49],j[0..199]. (X[i][j] == i*j)
&& forall i[50..99],j[0..199]. (X[i][j] == i*j))
```

Z3 prove result is valid,in other words,not of this assert is unsat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the question, but in general we cannot expect Z3 to solve all formulas with quantifiers. In this particular case it might help to enable the macro-finder, which propagates function definitions like the

```
(forall ... (= (try ...) def )))
```

which replaces all occurrences of `try` with `def`. The option name for that is `smt.macro_finder`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, your understand was right. I want replaces all occurrences of  try with it's definition.  after i enable the macro-finder, Z3 give me a valid answer.
       But now, there are an another question, I want chage the parament ,for example, the def  : 
    try(X, i, j) = (X[i][j] == i*j) , 
when I met  X[j][k] == j*k  , I want Z3 use try(X, j ,k)  to replace. so I use a new def:
    forall X,i,j.try(X, i, j) = (X[i][j] == i*j) . 
but Z3 return unknow when I prove :
X[j][k] == j*k  =>  try(X,j,k). Look forward to your favourable reply!

Comment: This really depends on the solvers and/or tactics you use. i*j over integers is not linear, so many solvers for linear arithmetic will give up very quickly. Perhaps the "nlsat" tactic would do the job? (for how to use  tactics see here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies)

Comment: If you just want to replace X[i][j] with something else, you could try to define the array in terms of new functions (like try), so that the macro finder does this job too.